# No overload for method getData

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-errors, tableadapter

I'm getting the compilation error no overload method takes three arguments.  I've cleaned and rebuild my solution, I've updated my stored procedures and rebuilt my table adapters numerous times and I dont know where the issue still lies.  When I preview my data in the ta I'm getting data and when I execute the procedure everything is working.  Let me know what else you may need to help out and any help is welcome.

Using c#

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
public Dictionary<string, double> Census(short vId, byte rType, byte sType) {
   using (dal.Analytic.DemoTableAdapters.CensusMapDataTa ta = new dal.Analytic.DemoTableAdapters.CensusMapDataTa())            
        {
            dal.Analytic.Demo.CensusMapDataDataTable dt = ta.GetData(varId, regionType, state_type);

            foreach (var row in dt) {
              data.Add(row.fips, row.dValue);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Look at the function definition.

Comment: What does the signature of `CensusMapData.GetData` look like?

Comment: Downvoted as @SLaks is right but a little bit rude.

Comment: @wonko79: I've always been annoyed by people who don't read error messages.  How would you say that more politely?

Comment: Look at the declaration for `CensusMapDataTa.GetData()`

Comment: What part of "a little bit rude" don't you understand ?

Comment: @SLaks: By leaving out the first part of the comment for sure :) and may be writing something like Jon Skeet. I understand you but you know some years ago...

Comment: No overload for method 'GetData' takes 3 arguments is the error

Comment: @wonko79: But that will just reinforce the notion that errors are incomprehensible things that people can't read.  I'm trying to get people to _read_ error messages, and to try to understand what the compiler is telling them.

Comment: Check the Signature of **GetData** method in **CensusMapDataTa** class.

Comment: @TroyBryant: SLaks, Jon Skeet and Charles allready found out and wanted to ask you to hover the mouse over ta.GetData so you can see what parameters this method requires. :)

Comment: so my understanding from the error message is that getData is supposed to receive three arguments.  It does receive three arguments so after that I've tried hard coding values rebuilding and few other things and nothing

Comment: @wonko79 it requires varId, regionType, state_type

Comment: @TroyBryant  its opposit of what you have written. **GetData** not supposed to receive 3 arguments as there is no method GetData which is taking 3 arguments.

Comment: @Troy Bryant: "No overload for method 'GetData' takes 3 arguments" starts with No. So you either provide to much parameters or you are missing some. Set the cursor to GetData and press F12.

Comment: @TroyBryant: Can you add the signature of GetData to your question as Jon Skeet requested. This will help us explain and anyone reading your question to understand.

Comment: @TroyBryant: The compiler is trying to tell you that that is not true.

Comment: Actually just traced the error back to the connection string.  The string was changed and my builds were failing because of the string so the table adapter was never updating.